# Can' set up my wifi - my wifi is redirecting to an IP to enter User Name and password

Tags: wifi, wpa

when I connect to my student dorm wifi network over my laptop it opens a browser window and redirects me to an website where i must enter my user name and password to connect to the internet.

I was trying to connect to the internet with my Raspberry Pi Zero W by changing the wpa_supplicant.conf but I couldn't figure what commands to write in that file to overcome this problem.

can you please help me?

Best Regards

Comment: If you've put in the credentials to connect to the network in wpa_supplicant it should connect and you'll just have to open the browser and go to the login page to login there.

Comment: I do not understand the problem. You don't know your user name and password to put into the web site by hand? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: if he is running headless how could he achieve that? I mean, often there are wifis that require you to log in via http either